# I want to create thumbnail of the image and both image and thumbnail will be store in a folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to upload the image using `<input type="file">` and I also want that when I clicked on upload button it creates its thumbnail and both "image" and "thumbnail" will be saved, I need help.

There is my code.
Here I have already reduce the size of the image but I couldn't auto download that file.

```js
var resizeImage = function(src,width,height) {
 var orig_src = new Image(),
 resize_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 orig_src.src = src;
 resize_canvas.width = width;
 resize_canvas.height = height;
 resize_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(orig_src, 0, 0, width, height);
 $(".resize-image").attr('src', resize_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
}
$(function(){
 resizeImage('thumb-1920-358764.jpg',100,100); // Image path, width, height
 
});
```

```html
<img class="resize-image" src="thumb-1920-358764.jpg" />`
```

```html
<img class="resize-image" src="thumb-1920-358764.jpg" />`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `<img>` elements' `crossOrigin` attribute to `"anonymous"`, create a `FormData()` object to store images as `File` objects, substitute using `canvas.toBlob()` for `.toDataURL()`, at `load` event of dynamically created `<img>` call `.toBlob()` on original image first at second `<canvas>` element, `.append()` the resulting `Blob` to `FormData` instance, then call `.toBlob()` on original `<canvas>` element and repeat call `.append()` to set both `Blob`s to `FormData`, which can the be posted to server using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()`

```js
var resizeImage = function(src, width, height, fd, input) {
  var orig_src = new Image(),
    resize_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  orig_src.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  orig_src.src = src;
  orig_src.onload = function() {
    resize_canvas.width = width;
    resize_canvas.height = height;
    resize_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(orig_src, 0, 0, width, height);
    var imageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    imageCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage($(".resize-image")[0], 0, 0);
    imageCanvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
      imageBlob = blob;
      fd.append("originalImage", blob);
    });

    resize_canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
      canvasBlob = blob;
      fd.append("resizedImage", blob);
      $(".resize-image")
        .attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      input.removeAttr("disabled");
    });
  }
}
$(function() {
  var canvasBlob, imageBlob, fd = new FormData(),
    input = $("input[type=button]");
  resizeImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Wikipedesketch1.png", 100, 100, fd, input); // Image path, width, height
  input.on("click", function() {
    for (let [key, prop] of fd) {
      console.log(key, prop)
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="resize-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Wikipedesketch1.png" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
<input type="button" value="upload" disabled>
```

Comment: could you please do some change ...actually when i click on upload button that original image and thumbnail will be save in a folder on my pc.

Comment: You can create a `.zip` file to include both image files, or download each file individually.

Comment: how can i download only thumbnail(resized) image after click on upload button.

Comment: You can use `<a>` element with `download` attribute set pass `Blob` to `URL.createObjectURL()`